# Is it advisable to store large strings in memory, or repeatedly read a file?

Tags: java, android

Let's say I have various text/json/xml/whatever files (stored locally, in the assets directory), ranging in size from 20 - 500 KB.  Assuming these files are going to be referenced frequently, throughout the application, is it better to:

A) Read the file once, the first time it's requested, and store the data in a variable

or

B) Read the file each time it's requested, grab the requested bit of information, and allow GC to clean up afterward?

Coming from web-dev, I generally use option (A), but I wonder if the storage limitation of mobile devices makes B preferred in this context (Android app development).

TYIA.

Comment: i don't think 500kb is too big to store..

Comment: a middleground might be to keep a reference to compressed bytes via gzip. then again, 500kb is not that big.

Comment: Doesn't it also kind of depent on the amount of files? I mean, if it's just a couple of 500kB, storing it in memory would be viable. But what if it's the unlikely scenario of having a couple of thousands of 500kB files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your data into memory by compressing it.That it will reduce your memory footprint at any point of time.So this technique can be applicable to both PCs and mobile phones.Later on when you need the data, read and decompress it.So read the file once, then compress and store it in the memory.The following example uses GZIPOutputStream to compress a string.

```
public static String compress(String str){
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
    gzip.write(str.getBytes());
    gzip.close();
    return out.toString("ISO-8859-1");
 }
```

Comment: can you explain how to compress XML or JSON data in the manner you're suggesting?

Comment: you can compress xml and json very much similar to string data.Convert xml or json string to byte array and use a GZIPOutputStream to write it.This is very much effective if data is sufficielntly large in size.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is being requested frequently, definitely it's better to read the file once and store in cache.

You can also read this article titled [How Google Taught me to Cache and Cash In](http://highscalability.com/how-google-taught-me-cache-and-cash) in HighScalability website.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the total size of the files, accessing frequency, and your targeting customers. Although high-end phone got very large memory, the are many low-ends system which has fewer memory. 
It might deserve to use some LRU cache to reach a balance.